# SPI setup for powerSTEP01

Tags: protocols, stm32, spi

i use an STM32F373CCT6 and need help with my SPI protocol, because my communication with a powerSTEP01 fails at the moment.
My SPI configuration is:

```
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

My array parameters:

```
        value_config_transmit[5] = 0x1A;
        value_config_transmit[4] = 0x2C;
        value_config_transmit[3] = 0x88;
        value_config_transmit[2] = 0x3A;
        value_config_transmit[1] = 0x00;
        value_config_transmit[0] = 0x00; 

        value_config_receive[5] = 0x00;
        value_config_receive[4] = 0x00;
        value_config_receive[3] = 0x00;
        value_config_receive[2] = 0x00;
        value_config_receive[1] = 0x00;
        value_config_receive[0] = 0x00;
```

And my code to write and read:

```
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //nSTBY/nRESET Pin is set
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //SPI_CS Pin set 
  HAL_Delay(100);


  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //SPI_CS Pin reset
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&value_config_transmit[5], 1, 100);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &value_config_receive[5], 1, 100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //SPI_CS Pin set
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //SPI_CS Pin reset
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&value_config_transmit[4], 1, 100);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &value_config_receive[4], 1, 100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //SPI_CS Pin set
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //SPI_CS Pin reset
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&value_config_transmit[3], 1, 100);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &value_config_receive[3], 1, 100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //SPI_CS Pin set
  HAL_Delay(100);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //SPI_CS Pin reset
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&value_config_transmit[2], 1, 100);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &value_config_receive[2], 1, 100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //SPI_CS Pin set
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //SPI_CS Pin reset
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&value_config_transmit[1], 1, 100);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &value_config_receive[1], 1, 100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //SPI_CS Pin set
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //SPI_CS Pin reset
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&value_config_transmit[0], 1, 100);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &value_config_receive[0], 1, 100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);   //SPI_CS Pin set
  HAL_Delay(100);
```

I tried to set the configuration register of the powerSTEP01 and for this i am using the SetParam()
command which(from my point of view, the datasheet is a little bit confusing) consists of the write part 000 and the Hexaddress 11010. These combined gives me an 8 bit command 0b00011010 == 0x1A.
After this byte i send two more bytes to change the config register of the powerSTEP01.

After that i want to read the config register back and want to see if i changed something. I do this with GetParam() which is 0b00111010 == 0x3A and two more received bytes which should show the config register configuration.

Sadly i am only receiving what i send and only zeros from the config register.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with my SPI configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t Powerstep01_Board_SpiInit(void)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef status;
  
  /* Initialises the SPI  --------------------------------------------------*/
  SpiHandle.Instance               = SPIx;
  SpiHandle.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32; 
  SpiHandle.Init.Direction         = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  SpiHandle.Init.CLKPhase          = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;    
  SpiHandle.Init.CLKPolarity       = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  SpiHandle.Init.CRCCalculation    = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  SpiHandle.Init.CRCPolynomial     = 7;
  SpiHandle.Init.DataSize          = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  SpiHandle.Init.FirstBit          = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  SpiHandle.Init.NSS               = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  SpiHandle.Init.TIMode            = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  
  SpiHandle.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  
  status = HAL_SPI_Init(&SpiHandle);
  
  return (uint8_t) status;
}
```

This is the configuration that worked for me in the nucleo-f030r8 board. SPIx is SPI1 in the nucleo-f030r8.

https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-spn3.html

If possible use the BSP provided by ST or take a look at their reference implementation to understand how the communication is established with the PoweSTEP01.